# My java code compiles, but on running shows error

Tags: java, compilation

When I compile the code below there are no errors, but when I run my code I end up with the following error:

> **Error: Could not find or load main class [name of class]**

I would be grateful if someone can explain the error to me in a simplified manner and how I can correct it.

**Examples of the code include**

```
  package Simulator;

  import javax.swing.JFrame;

  import java.awt.Graphics;

  public class Simulator extends JFrame{

  public Simulator(){

      setTitle("Simulator");

      setSize(500, 500);

      setResizable(false);

      setVisible(true);

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.drawString("HelloWorld!", 75, 75);

  }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Simulator();

    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing*;

import java.util.concurrent*;


public class SubmitLabelManipulationTasks {

  public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame(Hello Swing");
            final JLable label =  new JLabel("A Label");
            frame.add(label);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(300, 100)
            frame.setVisible(true);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()){
                  public void run(){
                        label.setText("Hey! This is Different!");
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code. That will explain us more better

Comment: because it can not find a main method that can be used as entry point for an application. Can you show your code?

Comment: Does the class you are calling in the java command having the method `public static void main(String[] args)`?

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Comment: Okay, I'll post the code now, and I'm using the command prompt and atom as the text editor, but I have also tried NetBeans.

Comment: It should be `public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {` instead of `public static void main (Strong [] args) throws Exception {` for `SubmitLabelManipulationTasks `

Comment: Take a closer look at `main(Strong[] args)`.

Comment: the parameter for `main()` which is called by jvm should be of type `String[]` not `Stong[]`

Answer (score 0):

your programs compile successfully because they dont have any compile error but you cant run your program because you dont have any main method or you are not specified your main method. Consider a simple class like :

```
class MyClass{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

this class have a `main` method so when your programs starts with this class it will call main method and printout `Hello World!`. Because you said that you are using net beans you could read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html) tutorial and see in **step 4** that you specify your class which contains the main method.

Comment: Hey, I tried this out, but it still comes up with the same error, is there anything else that I could be doing wrong? For example, when I run the first set of code I type 'java Simulator', and for the second set of code I type 'java SubmitLabelManipulationTask'. Thank you for posting that link, it was helpful in my understanding of java.

Answer (score -1):

If your source code name is HelloWorld.java, your compiled code will be HelloWorld.class

You will get that error if you call it using :

java HelloWorld.class
Instead, use this :

java HelloWorld
Hope it helps.

Comment: the OP does exactly that otherwise the error message would not come

Comment: Thank you for posting this, but I did do so, and it didn't help.

Answer (score -2):

I though You are using javac. In cmd it's like, in folder with file.java:

```
- javac file.java
- java file
```

But i highy suggest Eclipse for working with Java. Greetings.

Comment: the OP does exactly that otherwise the error message would not come

Comment: I have done that, however if always comes up with the same error message, even using just 'java file'.